# AWS SDK Kotlin is installed but can not be found in project

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, kotlin, amazon-s3

Im building a REST API and part of it shall be handling media upload and download to and from AWS S3.

Since im using Kotlin with Maven, I added a dependency to AWS S3 SDK to my pom.xml file like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aws.sdk.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    <version>0.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven install went well and everything passes together with my tests etc.

Problem occurs when im trying to add S3Client to my code, the whole SDK is not found.

The library is found in dependency tab in my InteliJ IDEA, also as part of external libraries as you can see on screenshot.

[image: AWS SDK is loaded in the dependencies, but not available to code.]

Due to this issue, im unable to move forward, as I cant really implement the S3 communication without actual client. I did try to restart IDEA if its not just some bug in IDE itself, but same issue occurs.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do, when I face these kinds of issues:

1. Try to run `mvn clean install` in a console. If this works, it is an issue with the IDE. If not, it's a maven issue.
2. If it's an issue with IntelliJ, try:

   a) "Reload All Maven Projects" in the Maven View

   b) File -> Invalidate Caches...

Answer (score 0):

You are installing the wrong package, see:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-kotlin/issues/760

Correct package has suffix "-jvm", example:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aws.sdk.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqs-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${awssdk.kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```